# Build custom iOS control which takes keyboard input

Tags: ios, events, keyboard

I'd like to build a custom iOS control which can take keyboard events from a physically keyboard connected to an iPad. I'd rather not subclass or otherwise make use of any of the existing high level UIKit classes but would rather receive and process the low level keyboard events themselves.

Is this even possible with an iOS app?

Answer (score 0):

Unless you are going to implement your own keyboard (not recommended - it's wrong on so many levels including internationalisation/foreign language support), you'll need to either use an instance of UITextField or UITextView or subclass one of these classes.  AFAIK (and I've looked into it in some depth) there is no other way to trigger the on-screen keyboard in iOS.

Answer (score 0):

You might try looking in the [ExternalAccessory](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/navigation/index.html#section=Frameworks&topic=ExternalAccessory) framework - maybe you could find an open source implementation of the USB keyboard interface and put that to work.